# 2x2 Matrix with no zero entries where $A^k=0$ - Nilpotence?

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

Find an example of a $2x2$ matrix $A$ that has no zero entries but is such that $A^K=0$ for some positive integer k.

Here is my thinking: When $k=1, A=0$, but this contradicts that the matrix has no zero entries, so no such matrix exists. Then I started reading about nilpotence and I got very confused. Can someone explain this to me? What am I missing?

Why isn't it that no such matrix exists, considering k=1?

Comment: You are reading "for some $k$ " as "for every $k$".

Comment: WOW! You are so right. Problem solved, clearly I need to take a break and drink some more coffee. Thank you Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pmatrix{1&-1\cr 1&-1}$ is an example

Comment: But when $k=1, A=0$ and that is not the case here?Am I doing $A^1$ wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If $k=1$ and $A^k=0$ then $A^1=A=0$, i.e., $A$ is the zero matrix, with zero entries, so there is no solution to $A^k=0$ with $k=1$ and $A$ having non-zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

Let the matrix $A$ have elements

$a$   $b$

$c$   $d$

You get $A^2=0$ if the characteristic polynomial

$\det(A-\lambda I)=(\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+(ad-bc))=0$

Then $d=-a$ and $bc=ad=-a^2$.

Try out various values of $a$ and $b$, work out $c$ and $d$ from the equations just derived, and watch what happens.

Comment: Why isn't it that no such matrix exists, considering k=1?

Comment: Matrices are funny that way.  You don't have $A×A=0$ implying $A=0$ like ordinary numbers.  And this exercise proves it.  You will run into lots of different sets of quantities that do this kind of thing, especially when you study residue-class (modular) arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Then write down the matrix equation

$$A.A = 0$$

This gives you four equations (one for each position in the Matrix equation)

Solving these equations for $a$ and $b$ gives you the solution

$$A_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -\frac{a^2}{b} & -a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

valid for any $a$ but $b\ne 0$.

If $b=0$ the solution is

$$A_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 c & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

for any $c$.

By symmetry, if $c=0$ we have for any $b$

$$A_3 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & b \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice that $A_3 = A_1(a=0)$.